# Singleton that will hold an instance of Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, retrofit, okhttp

So I have created a login that will take an username and password input from the user, encode it with `Base64` in order to create a **token** in the format: `("Authorization", AUTH)` where `AUTH = "Basic " + Base64 encoding` of user and password. This is sent via `Headers`.

So, in the end, it looks like this: `Authorization: Basic XXXXXX`, where `XXXXXX` is the user **token**.

And then it will check whether or not that user exists in the database via an API request.

I am using `Retrofit` and `OkHttp3` in the same class as `RetrofitClient` and this class is responsible for using the API and adding those `Headers`.

Later, I use the `RetrofitClient` class on the Login Activity.

What I need to do now, is make this "**token**" available to all the other activities by creating a `Singleton` that will store the data of the `Retrofit` after a successful login. But I do not know how to do this.

I started learning Kotlin and Android 3 weeks ago.

Here is my code:

**GET_LOGIN.kt**

```
interface GET_LOGIN {
    @GET("login")
    fun getAccessToken() : Call<String>
}
```

**RetrofitClient.kt**

```
class RetrofitClient {

    fun login(username:String, password:String){
        val credentials = username + ":" + password
        val AUTH = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), Base64.DEFAULT).trim()
        retrofit = init(AUTH)
    }


    // Initializing Retrofit
    fun init(AUTH: String) : Retrofit{

        // Creating the instance of an Interceptor
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY


        // Creating the OkHttp Builder
        val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()


        // Creating the custom Interceptor with Headers
        val interceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain?.request()?.newBuilder()?.addHeader("Authorization", AUTH)?.build()
            chain?.proceed(request)
        }
        client.addInterceptor(interceptor) // Attaching the Interceptor
        //client.addInterceptor(logging) // Attaching the Interceptor



        // Creating the instance of a Builder
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://srodki.herokuapp.com/")   // The API server
                .client(client.build())                             // Adding Http Client
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) // Object Converter
                .build()
        return retrofit
    }
    lateinit var retrofit : Retrofit

    fun providesGetLogin(): GET_LOGIN = retrofit.create(GET_LOGIN::class.java)

}
```

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
    var RetrofitClient : RetrofitClient = RetrofitClient()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)



        loginBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val user = userTxt.text.toString()
            val pass = passTxt.text.toString()


            if (validateLogin(user, pass)){
                login(user, pass)
            }
        }
    }


    fun validateLogin(user: String, pass: String): Boolean {
        if (user == null || user.trim().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Missing Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return false
        }
        if (pass == null || pass.trim().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Missing Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    fun login(user: String, pass: String) {

        RetrofitClient.login(user, pass)
        val apiLogin = RetrofitClient.providesGetLogin().getAccessToken()
        apiLogin.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    if(response.body()?.code == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, List_usersActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Login Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Login Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first and foremost, please use camel case on java and kotlin. We have standards in java and kotlin on programming. And i can see that you are trying to do DI, but, thats not how you do it in Android.
Anyways, you could do this a couple of ways without even using a singleton but by saving it on a storage. Options are Shared Preferences, Local Storage and SQLite. But, if you insist on using a singleton. You can do it like this:

```
object MySingleton { // This is how you declare singletons in kotlin
    lateinit var token: String;
}
```

## EDIT

So, from your comment, it looked like you need to store the token. You could start by using sharedpreferences(database would be better) and store the token there. I assume you don't know how to so here is an example:

```
val sp = SharedPreferences("sp", 0);
sp.edit().putString("token", theTokenVariable); // not sure of this function
sp.edit().apply(); // you could use commit if you dont mind sharedpreferences to lag your screen(if it ever will)
```

Now how do you get the token from retrofit? The only way i could help you right now is that you could retrieve the response body from the response variable you receive from onResponse of the retrofit call. From there it is your problem mate. I don't know how your response is formatted, how it should be retrieved etc. ***A recommendation would be to format it as JSON.***

Comment: Yes, but how would you apply to this case? Im already aware of how Singletons are created in Kotlin.

Comment: I don't understand you. If you know how singletons work, then what don't you understand?

Comment: How to store the data of `RetrofitClient` after a successful login and use it on future classes. Do I need a new class? Do I use companion object inside `RetrofitClient `class? How do I code it is the question. And there are parameters.